# Debug Gazebo (without ROS) using GDB

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How is it possible to use gdb to debug Gazebo.

I do not use ROS, only Gazebo 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 (a bit old but I have other dependencies that require me to use 14.04). I built Gazebo from source and it worked fine. Following the instructions I used the command :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
```

to make sure I will be able to use gdb but when I start the program with gdb and I make the program crash, the stack is always empty. Should this be because I did not configure or start gdb correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16121/debug-gazebo-(without-ros)-using-gdb/) by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-05-09**:
Are you starting gzserver and gzclient separately? Running gdb on both?

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-05-10**:
No I was running both at the same time using gazebo instead of gzserver  and then gzclient as was suggested to me on the other answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Instead of using `gazebo`, you have to use `gzserver  <world>`, and then, `gzclient`.

E.g. for debugging `gzserver`:

```
gdb gzserver
r <your_world>
```

Once `gzserver` is running, you can launch `gzclient` if you want.

Alternatively, you can just launch `gzserver` as usual:

```
gzserver <your_world>
```

And run `gdb` on `gzclient` with:

```
gdb gzclient
r
```

Take a look at this [related question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15749/how-to-enable-debugging-for-a-plugin/) too.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) on 2017-05-10**:
Ah you're right! I was running both server and client at the same time. Thanks it works!